# How to close Custom android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I have created a custom `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder` and instead of using set positive and negative buttons I have designed a custom layout through xml (haveing ok and cancel buttons) and have assigned it to custom `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder`.

I have set on click listeners on ok and cancel buttons. My problem is on click of cancel button I have set a callback to main fragment where I want to close/dismiss the dialog, but I am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

how to fix this?

here is my code:

```
cancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Listener.OnCancel(); }});
@Override
public void OnCancel() {
final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = custompopup.show();
dialog.cancel()}
```

Note that: Click listener on cancel button is in Custom class and OnCancel is in Main fragment, and custompopup is object of custom class and this object is initialized in a function that is a part of main fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the `Dialog` is already open or not. If it is open, then close it like this:

Declare global:

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog;
```

Show dialog:

```
dialog = custompopup.show();
```

Dismiss `Dialog`  in your listener like this:

```
@Override
public void OnCancel() {
  if (dialog.isShowing()) {
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = custompopup.show();**

Before this line you need to dismiss your previous dialog. You can't create new one until you dismiss previous the previous one.

Try this:

```
dialog.dismiss();
final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = custompopup.show();
```

your **onCancel** should look like this:

```
@Override
public void OnCancel() {
dialog.cancel()
if(dialog.isShowing(){
   dialog.dismiss();
  }
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = custompopup.show();
}
```

Comment: but in your question it is not dismissed. You are directly calling new one, you need to dismiss previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception because you are again showing the same dialog which is already shown.
You are doing this thing in `onCancel()`.

You do not need to cancel/dismiss dialog in onCancel, its handled by system. onCancel will only call when dialog is cancelled by user, then its dismissed, no need to dismiss/cancel manually.